# how to select records where a project is assigned for a person and also records of same project assigned to other persons?

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic

A project is assigned to multiple persons, each with different project quantity. Supposing project A is assigned as below:

```
P1 - Qty 50
P2 - Qty 120
P3 - Qty 75
```

My Table structure is:

```
Project - AssignedPerson - AssignedDate - AssignedQty 
ProjectA - P1            - 12/01/2016   - 50
ProjectA - P2            - 12/01/2016   - 120
ProjectA - P3            - 12/01/2016   - 75
ProjectB - P1            - 15/01/2016   - 210
ProjectB - P3            - 16/01/2016   - 90
ProjectC - P2            - 17/01/2016   - 110
ProejctC - P3            - 17/01/2016   - 120
```

Now say person P1 is logged in and seeing his assignments. 
I want to show him records like below -

```
Project - AssignedPerson - AssignedDate - AssignedQty 
ProjectA - P1            - 12/01/2016   - 50
ProjectA - P2            - 12/01/2016   - 120
ProjectA - P3            - 12/01/2016   - 75
ProjectB - P1            - 15/01/2016   - 210
ProjectB - P3            - 16/01/2016   - 90
```

Above list shows records for P1 and also records that show how much qty is
assigned to others for the projects assigned to P1.
How to accomplish this?

Comment: Could you specify your table/s structure and post more info? Think we don't know anything about what you're working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a variable for the desired person, let's say `@person`. Then your query would look like this in case that person is `P1`:

```
declare @person nvarchar(10) = 'P1'
select * from TABLE_NAME where AssignedPerson = @person or project in (select project from TABLE_NAME t1 where t1.assignedperson = @person)
```